# Did El capitan broke my brew installed php?

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I have tried almost everything to fix this, but nothing helped me,
I am using OSX 10.11.4 El Capitan, I have installed homebrew and php55 with it, version 5.5.34.
I am using some php extensions along with it, for example pgsql.
Once I have upgraded to Capitan I had to solve some problems with apache but it was not a big problem, but for the php, it looks like it stopped loading my extensions. As I kind of noob in this I don't really know what info to share. This is my apache error_lo which is repeating:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.34/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pgsql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.34/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pgsql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
[Thu Apr 28 14:21:12.002839 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27896] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) PHP/5.5.34 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 28 14:21:12.002910 2016] [core:notice] [pid 27896] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

When I try to go to the extension folder it is not even there, only a folder called build is in the /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.34/lib/php

Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is probably better asked over at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: I think its because, 2 different PHP version are present in your system. Check and install, unlink one.

Comment: I have never had a problem with having more php versions on my computer, and when I try to unlink through brew it will give me an error:
No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php

Comment: I think you should reinstall php + extentions because you have libraries issues. For example you compiled apache + mod_php for one platform and php_pgsql.dll was build for anather platform. When you are calling (dlopen) `php_pgsql.dll` from apache it uses another symbols and can't load it or can't find the dependencies. For such problems we are using DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (LD_LIBRARY_PATH on other *nix)

Comment: @Machavity This isn't a server administration question. Homebrew and Mac OS X are tools typically used on a desktop system.

Comment: @duskwuff They are, but SO really isn't for infrastructure questions. Server Fault has an [OSX section](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mac-osx)

Comment: Guys, I have found out that the problem was that I had errors when installing php55 with pgsql and the problem was solved by running xcode-select --install  command. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution for installing `php --with-pgsql` is to install `xcode` in console first.